# laravel slug post not working for Bangla language but English work fine

Tags: laravel, slug

```
$data['slug']  = str_replace(' ','-', $request->slug);
```

Results in the error

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the other way to approach this.

use laravel slug `str_slug($request->slug)`